# Handling application images with Firebase

Tags: javascript, image, firebase

I'm using the following workflow to handle images on my web application using firebase (JavaScript):

1. Upload image original image to firebase using `firebase.storage`
2. I use firebase functions to listen when the image finalize uploading and I generate a smaller optimized image
3. I save the name and url of the new generated image into firestore
4. I delete the original image from the firebase bucket to save space

This is working perfectly, but I can't figure out a way to get **the resized image url** back in the app once above process is done.

I would like to show a progress bar to the user while the image is being uploaded and resized and display the image once the process is done.

Is there a way to listen when a firebase function is finished?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have any code you tried?

Comment: Hi, 

I followed [this example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/generate-thumbnail/functions/index.js) for the image resizing part.

 And for the upload of the original image on the web app I used [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files).

But I don't have any code to display the resulting image yet because that's the part I don't know how to code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to signal back to a client when a background function has finished.

The typical way to accomplish this is to let the client pass in a unique ID when it starts the background function, e.g. like a push ID from the database, or the path for the image, and then have the function write the status of each operation to that path in the Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore.

So in steps:

1. Client uploads image to a specific path
2. Client then starts [waiting for status updates in the database](https://gist.github.com/puf/146fecdae240ac0e62f858f7650aa85f) based on that path
3. Cloud Functions is triggered and performs the resize operation
4. Once the resize is done, the Cloud Function write the path to the database
5. Client gets the new path and completes the operation